# PhpStorm 2021.2 Syntax errors not going away even after they are fixed

Tags: php, phpstorm, syntax-highlighting

This issue seems to appear after I have updated to the latest version 2021.2 but I am not sure if this is the cause of my problem.

The problem is that, when I am editing the PHP file, the syntax error doesn't go away even I am very certain that I have fixed the highlighted error.

Here are a few examples:

1. When I write something like `$x = 1;`, the editor prompts me that the local variable `$x` is unused. Fine. But this won't go away even I use `$x` later on.
2. I use the autocomplete feature a lot. So for example when I want to type `$this->getSomeObject($id)`, I can only just type `$this->getS` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to let PhpStorm outputs something like "$this->getSomeObject()".

   Now, as `getSomeObject()` expects a parameter, PhpStorm would underline this line with red, saying that "Required parameter $id is missing". Fine. However, this error won't go away even I fill in the missing piece.
   Which means that the IDE will still underline the line `$this->getSomeObject($id)` and complain that I "Required parameter $id is missing".

I see similar problems everywhere in my code, where PhpStorm reports of "unused local variable", "required parameter missing", "undefined variable" etc. never go away. Not even after I reopen the offending file.

Reopening the project can eliminate the outdated error highlights, but similar errors will occur again.

I even try invalidating caches (**File/invalidate caches, restart**).

**An Example :**

[image: warning_not_disappear.png]

**Version :**

```
PhpStorm 2021.2
Build #PS-212.4746.100, built on July 28, 2021
Licensed to orhan erday
Subscription is active until December 21, 2021.
For educational use only.
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b1504.13 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 2996M
Cores: 12
Registry: run.processes.with.pty=TRUE, ide.balloon.shadow.size=0
Non-Bundled Plugins: String Manipulation (8.15.203.000.3), intellij.prettierJS (212.4746.57), de.espend.idea.laravel (0.15.4), de.espend.idea.php.annotation (8.0.0), fr.adrienbrault.idea.symfony2plugin (0.23.210), ru.adelf.idea.dotenv (2021.3.0.212), com.laravel_idea.plugin (4.3.4.212)
```

Comment: Please disable **Grazie** plugin,restart and try again. Any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to check the `idea.log` file (`Help | Show log in XXX`) for possible exceptions etc.

But right now for me it looks like it could be https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-275168.

If the above is your case then please disable bundled **Grazie plug**, restart PhpStorm and check again -- any better?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that somehow only affects Turkish users.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-275168

To work the issue around, you can disable the Grazie plugin at `Settings | Plugins`.

I hope the Grazie devs to fix that soon.

Comment: It surprised me that this was the reason and it made sense. Thanks for the answer.